# How to run raw SQL queries with Sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I am not clear yet on the proper way to run raw SQL queries with Sequel.

Currently I am trying this:

```
DB.fetch("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE dialcode = '#{@dialcode}' LIMIT 1") do |row|
 @zonename = row
end
```

How can I can run the queries as raw SQL then access the results like normal?

```
if @zonename.name = "UK"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have a few pointers which may be useful:

1. You could simply do:

   ```
    @zonename = DB.fetch("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE dialcode = ? LIMIT 1", @dialcode).first
   ```

NB: you are ignoring the fact that there could be more results matching the criteria. If you expect multiple possible rows to be returned then you probably want to build an array of results by doing ...

```
    @zonename = DB.fetch("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE dialcode = ? LIMIT 1", @dialcode).all
```

and processing all of them.

2. The return set is a hash. If `@zonename` points to one of the records then you can do

   ```
    @zonename[:column_name]
   ```

to refer to a field called "column_name".  You can't do `@zonename.column_name` (you could actually decorate `@zonename` with helper methods using some meta-programming but let's ignore that for the moment).

Sequel is an excellent interface, the more you learn about it the more you'll like it.

Answer (score 22):

Note that instead of:

```
DB.fetch("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE dialcode = '#{@dialcode}' LIMIT 1")
```

you should do:

```
DB.fetch("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE dialcode = ? LIMIT 1", @dialcode)
```

Otherwise, you open yourself to SQL injection if you don't control the contents of `@dialcode`.

Comment: Could you tell me what method is called by `fetch` under the hood to escape the user input? I have a complex query that is built up with many methods and need to escape the user input separately from my database call, while building the query.

Comment: sorry, just found it in the docs (which I was reading while searching this, will post it here for others): https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/cf1e987c1c2f7e74dca5c0f8312149bede659a21/doc/security.rdoc . The method is `DB.literal(my_insecure_string)`. Thanks for the library Jeremy.