# In SQL, how can I select a modified column?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sequel

I am trying to do this using SQL in Ruby:

```
SELECT number*2 FROM dictionary;
```

I can use `.select(:number)` to get the number columns "as is", but I have no idea how to return them modified. I tried this (which obviously didn't work):

```
current_table.select(:number*2)
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144813/proper-way-to-run-raw-sql-queries-with-sequel

Comment: Or, use a "virtual row" with operators, see http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/virtual_rows_rdoc.html#label-Operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either of these

```
@newnumber = number.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ?", @dictionary.id], :select => "number * 2 as newnumber")

@newnumber = number.all(:conditions=>"id='#{@dictionary.id}'",:select=>"number * 2 as newnumber")
```