# Execute a sql query from within a Ruby Cucumber Step definition

Tags: sql, ruby, cucumber

Never tried this before,
 I am trying to  execute
a sql query from within  a Ruby Cucumber Step definition .
Not at all sure what to do after the connection made.

Connection (Works)

Then(/^TC-0001-Bill-Of-Laiding Query onleLisa (Lisa_One) to access existing Bill Of laiding Order$/) do

```
conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:GPAutomation','XXXXX','XXXXX')
conn.connected?

Framework Setup

require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'
require 'cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'win32ole'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
require 'yaml'
require 'dbi'


The Query that I want to execute 

select h.bol_id,  * from bol_header h (nolock) 
inner join bol_header_info hi (nolock) on h.bol_id = hi.bol_id
where h.facility_id = '505' and h.Status = 'O' and hi.order_type = 'S'
```

Any Pro tips would be greatly appreciated …

Comment: You may want to check out sequel - http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/.  To run your SQL queries - http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Arbitrary+SQL+queries.

Comment: And to connect to your DB - http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html#label-Using+the+Sequel.connect+method

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us your back-end database. Assuming that it is SQLite3 software. you would

```
gem install sqlite3
```

Ruby code would look like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'

DBNAME = "hello.sqlite"
File.delete(DBNAME) if File.exists?DBNAME

DB = SQLite3::Database.new( DBNAME )
DB.execute("CREATE TABLE testdata(class_name, method_name)")

# Looping through some Ruby data classes
insert_query = "INSERT INTO testdata(class_name, method_name) VALUES(?, ?)"

[Numeric, String, Array, IO, Kernel, SQLite3, NilClass, MatchData].each do |klass|
  puts "Inserting methods for #{klass}"

  # a second loop: iterate through each method
  klass.methods.each do |method_name|
    # Note: method_name is actually a Symbol, so we need to convert it to a String
    # via .to_s
    DB.execute(insert_query, klass.to_s, method_name.to_s)
  end
end
```

I pulled this from a [Dan Nguyen](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/sql/) web page.  Look there for more.

Comment: Thanks for your respnse ... It's SQL

Comment: @user3233238 Tell us the database engine.  E.g. Oracle, MySql, Microsoft SQL Server, DB2, Microsoft Access, SQLLite, etc.,.  My advice is google <your SQL-engine> **ruby example**

Comment: @user3233238 search [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144813/proper-way-to-run-raw-sql-queries-with-sequel)

Comment: Thanks , This is exactly where I am  with this . I am trying to resolve the following -  uninitialized constant DB (NameError)
as used with DB.run select h.bol_id,  * from;bol_header (nolock)
inner join bol_header_info hi (nolock);on h.bol_id = hi.bol_id
where h.facility_id = '505' and h.Status = 'O' and hi.order_type = 'S'

Comment: Notice that in my (well, Dan's) example that DB is initialized **DB = SQLite3::Database.new( DBNAME )**.  If you initialized yours remember ruby [scoping rules](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#What_is_Variable_Scope.3F) for variables.

Comment: You initialize *conn* but then never use it.