# How to put a raw SQL query in Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am trying to convert SQL code to Seqel to run it from my script. How do I convert this:

```
select code, count(1) as total 
from school_districts 
group by code order by total desc;
```

into Sequel? Or, is there a way to pass raw SQL to Sequel? Also the `school_districts` will be interpolated `#{table_name}`.

Comment: This is documented in the Sequel cheatsheet: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Using+raw+SQL. That said, it's _NOT_ a good idea to use raw SQL if you can help it. The idea of an ORM is it allows you to write queries that are independent of the DBM you are talking to. That lets you easily change to another DBM without changing your code.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3144813/128421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it a couple ways:

1. Use `[]`:

   ```
   DB["your sql string"]
   ```
2. Use `fetch`:

   ```
   DB.fetch("your sql string")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
DB[:school_districts].select(:code).group_and_count(:code).reverse_order(:count)
```

is a Sequel way of executing that query. I did not however alias the count column, but I hope you can do with this.

Even though working in Sequel is preferable as it allows you to change DBMs without changing your code I would prefer you use the `fetch` method.